# How to adjust many widgets with the MDTopAppBar?

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

This is the kivy file

```
MDScreen:
    name: "scr 3"
    height: root.height - toolbar.height - dp(40)
    MDTabs:
    #tab_padding:[10,10,10,10]
        tab_indicator_anim:True
        tab_ba[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwO8O.png)r_height:'70dp'
        Tab:
            title:'All Doctors'
            icon:'doctor'
            font_style:'H5'
            bold:True
            title_icon_mode:'Top'
            MDLabel:
                text:'Doctors'
                font_style:'H5'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.775}
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_y: True
                do_scroll_x: False
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: root.height - toolbar.height - dp(40)
                    padding: 10
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'vertical'
                        cols: 1
                        id: doc_list
                        spacing: "15dp"
                        padding: "15dp"
                        adaptive_height: True
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5}
```

---

This is the screen class python code

```
def values(self):
    card = self.ids.doc_list
    for i in range(APP.get_total_doc()):
        if APP.get_doctor(i)==[]:
            continue
        else:
            email,n,qlf,exp,fee=APP.get_doctor(i)
            card_widget = DocShowCard()
            card_widget.ids.name.text = '  '+n
            card_widget.ids.qlf.text = qlf
            card_widget.ids.exp.text = exp+'years of exp.'
            card_widget.ids.fee.text = 'Rs. '+fee
            card_widget.ids.email.text = email
                #word_widget.ids.words.text = slowo
            card.add_widget(card_widget)
```

`DocShowCard` is a Custom MDCard which accepts all the details of doctors.

The widgets should be stacked properly and scrolling should be done smoothly

The widgets are stacked from bottom to top but should be from top to bottom.